# FATAL: could not access private key file “/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key”: Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, ssl

I believe I ended up mixing up permissions at /etc/ssl directories tree as the last modification was made on 18th November and a day after I could not get my PostgreSQL to work.

When I type in

> sudo service postgresql start

I get

> FATAL: could not access private key file “/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key”: Permission denied

Checking permissions

> ~$ sudo -i
>   ~$ ls -la /etc/ssl/private
>   drw-r----- 2 root     ssl-cert 4096 Nov 18 21:10 .
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 postgres postgres 1704 Set  4 11:26 ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

Checking group composition

> ~$ id postgres
>   uid=114(postgres) gid=127(postgres) groups=127(postgres),114(ssl-cert)

Also I noticed that my ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem file at /etc/ssl/certs/ doesn't have a symlink. I don't know if this makes any difference...

Please, help me sort this out.

Thanks.

Edit: Should it be posted on **serverfault** instead?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try adding `postgres` user to the group `ssl-cert`

Run the below code to fix your issue:

```
# > It happened to me and it turned out that I removed erroneously the postgres user from "ssl-cert" group, set it back with
sudo gpasswd -a postgres ssl-cert

# Fixed ownership and mode
sudo chown root:ssl-cert  /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
sudo chmod 740 /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

# now postgresql starts! (and install command doesn't fail anymore)
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

courtsey to [GabLeRoux](https://gist.github.com/GabLeRoux/0c60f9be0c28b6b41f64cb55474b0ccb)

Comment: If the permissions of the file are set up correctly, the problem may be caused by one of the parent directories up the hierarchy not having the execute (x) permission. This is required to traverse the directories leading up to the file.

Comment: @Seth Thank you so much for the 'x' permission hint. Saved me a lot of headache.

Answer (score 12):

Check the output of

```
$ sudo -u postgres
$ cd /etc/ssl/private
$ ls
```

If the response is "Permission denied" do

```
$ chown postgres:ssl-cert /etc/ssl/private/
$ chown postgres:postgres /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Comment: Then I got also the error
`File must be owned by the database user or root, must have no write permission for "group", and must have no permissions for "other"`
So I changed the permissions with:
`sudo chmod 510 /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key`
Now, everything work fine :)

Comment: @ChristophSchranz Thanks! Following your comment fixed the issue for me as well.

Answer (score 7):

### Only thing that will work if you have changed permissions for /etc/ssl/private

```sh
mkdir /etc/ssl/private-copy; mv /etc/ssl/private/* /etc/ssl/private-copy/; rm -r /etc/ssl/private; mv /etc/ssl/private-copy /etc/ssl/private; chmod -R 0700 /etc/ssl/private; chown -R postgres /etc/ssl/private
```

Copy this whole command (It's a one line code).

> If this doesn't work for you, ckeck your postgres user groups by `groups postgres` and make sure your postgres user have **ssl-cert root postgres** (Order doesn't matter).

#### Now lets check your file permissions on ssl/private :

```
$ ls -la /etc/ssl/
> drwx------   2 postgres root private
```

If this is not the output change your permissions with `sudo chmod -R 700 /etc/ssl/private` and for owners `chown -R postgres:root /etc/ssl/private`

```
//Now check permissions on ssl-cert-snakeoil.key, 
//which will be inside your **private** directory.
$ ls -la /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
> -rwx------ 1 postgres root /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Answer (score 3):

I was suffering from this issue when attempting to start Postgresql on a remote docker instance.  I **eventually** tracked down the crazy solution [here](https://github.com/puntonim/docker-postgresql93/issues/2).  Basically you have to recreate the directories, chown on it's own doesn't work:

```
mkdir /etc/ssl/private-copy; mv /etc/ssl/private/* /etc/ssl/private-copy/; rm -r /etc/ssl/private; mv /etc/ssl/private-copy /etc/ssl/private; chmod -R 0700 /etc/ssl/private; chown -R postgres /etc/ssl/private
```

Answer (score 2):

This error was preventing my **PostgreSQL** server from running locally.

The following worked for me:

```
sudo chown postgres:postgres /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key 
sudo chmod 600               /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Also make sure that `/etc/ssl/private` has enough permissions.

---

Some programs can be incredibly pedantic and cost you valuable hours. By running `journalctl` after `sudo systemctl start postgresql` I'd see various errors like:

```
FATAL:  could not load private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key": Permission denied

FATAL:  private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key" must be owned by the database user or root

FATAL:  private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key" has group or world access
DETAIL:  File must have permissions u=rw (0600) or less if owned by the database user, or permissions u=rw,g=r (0640) or less if owned by root.
```

I couldn't make it with work `sudo chmod root:root`, so I had to settle for `sudo chmod postgres:postgres`.

---

EDIT

I haven't tried it, but running deleting and regenerating the snakeoil certificate might work as well:

```
make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite
```

(You may have to run it with sudo, don't know.)

Comment: If the PostgreSQL server ist meant to be used only locally, you should just disable SSL. But since you called it "pedantic", I think you're generally unwilling to learn, expect things to work out of the box, and do not care for security.

Answer (score 1):

I had other certificates under `/etc/ssl/private` and hence, changing permissions recursively was out of question.

I tried adding `postgres` user to `ssl-cert` group that didn't help either.

I modified the permission of `/etc/ssl/private` to 716, basically saying that anyone else other than root (user) and ssl-cert (group) can read and execute the directory.

`sudo chmod 716 /etc/ssl/private`

Then, I modified the ownership of `ssl-cert-snakeoil.key`

`sudo chown postgres:postgres /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key`

This worked for me, basically a combination of the answers by @devops and @Noushad

Answer (score 0):

Try setting permissions on the .key file to 600.  Postgres doesn't like key files with group or world permissions set.  You may also need to change the owner to postgres, though I'm not sure about that.

Comment: No changes, thanks for the attempt though. I'm desperate.

Comment: What are the permissions on the /etc/ssl/private directory?

Comment: Also, what version of postgres?  Incidentally, we have our server.key file in /var/lig/pgsql/data.

Comment: Postgre version is 9.4.5 and /etc/ssl/private permissions are drw-r----- 2 root ssl-cert 4096 Nov 18 21:10

Comment: Try removing group read permissions from /etc/ssl/private - 600 instead of 640.  I haven't verified this, but I've seen it suggested elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I am running the postgres server in WSL, and I was facing the error with the ssl-cert file. I managed to make it work by changing the owner of the file to the postgres user I had created, adding the expected user and group IDs to the user as required of the application (111 and 116, respectively, as gleaned from helpful error messages), and voila, I have an active server from within WSL.

```
sudo useradd postgres
sudo usermod -u 111 -g 116 -a -G ssl-cert postgres
sudo chown postgres /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

After running the above, there were two more files the user running the server (postgres for me) needed permission to access, both residing in `/var/postgresql`. I used `sudo chown --` twice more to give ownership to postgres. Running `sudo service postgresql start` will tell you which files you'll need to transfer ownership of through any error messages.