# postgres FATAL: could not access private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key": Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ssl

By running `sudo service postgresql start` (pg 9.3 on ubuntu 14.04), the  following error is raised:

```
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
 * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2016-06-28 11:17:54 IRDT FATAL:  could not access private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key": Permission denied
   ...fail!
```

I've seen the similar questions but non of the workarounds have solved the problem for me.

Might ne usefull:

```
root@Sn00p:/etc/ssl/private# ls -la /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key 
-rw-r----- 1 postgres postgres 1704 ژانوی 16 19:46 /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Any idea?

Comment: what this `sudo -u postgres sh -c 'ls -la /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'` shows ?..

Comment: @VaoTsun `-rw-r----- 1 postgres postgres 1704 ژانوی 16 19:46 /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key`

Comment: If it's not the file that lacks permissions, it's one of the directories of the hierarchy leading to it. Try `ls -ld` on each directory. The `x` bit must be set for others for a non-owner of a directory to traverse it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FATAL: could not access private key file “/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key”: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209661/fatal-could-not-access-private-key-file-etc-ssl-private-ssl-cert-snakeoil-key)